# Does TPU Accelerators are supported in Unified AI Platform

Tags: google-ai-platform

I have some custom training jobs in AI Platform using GPUs & TPUs and trying to run the same jobs in unified AI platform but not able to find the TPU machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Looking into the AI Platform Unified documentation able to find [GPUs
  configurations](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/MachineSpec#acceleratortype) but nothing about TPUs. Looks like TPU’s are not
  supported by unified.
- You can look into the AI Platform Unified [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/resources/release-notes) updates
  to check update about this feature